# Ethernet Wall Sockets - Wiring Issue

Tags: ethernet, cat6, wiring

I have a strange issue with my home network I'm trying to fix. Please see the pictures below….

[image: Connecting 2 Wall Plugs]

[image: Type B / Per-Label Config]

Any ideas as to why this isn't working?

Thanks, J

EDITS:
Just to add a bit more information... as I was fed up of running up and down stairs all the time, I've removed the ports from the walls and am running a stripped down cable directly between the two. The top picture is literally a shot of them on my desk and the stripped-wires are about 3 inches long.

Testing is then just carrying them directly to the Router and intersecting an existing connection (i.e. my XBOX). I get no link lights and no power lights, are the ports-themselves broken?

And I used a proper (well, cheap plastic) tool to push the wires down into the housing.

After feedback from Tetsujin and Tonny, I've ordered a proper-metal to push the wires down with and a network cable tester to see which ports light up. Thanks to Amazon - I'll should be able to report back with findings tomorrow.

Thanks Tetsujin and Tonny for the responses so far.

Comment: Have you tested it for continuity? Did you punch it down with a proper tool? It doesn't look like it. The tool should cut too, leaving all ends identical & tucked down. How much of it have you unravelled? You don't want it pretty, you want it tight to as close as you can get.

Comment: Yes it was all punched down with a  proper tool

What I've done in these photos is removed the sockets from the wall plugs, stripped down a network cable and ran connections direct from one to the other. I then plug one end into the router and another into a device - no link or connectivity lights whatsoever.

Comment: Are both connector blocks in the top picture the ends of the same cable? The color-coding looks OK, but I agrtee with Tetsujin that it doesn't look as if you used the proper tool to press the individual wires in the clamps. And why did you strip back the outer insulation so far? That isn't needed at all.

Comment: By 'proper tool' do you mean an actual proper one, metal with a sprung mechanism & cutter, or plastic one for 2 bucks from walmart? It really looks like option 2. the cheap ones often don't make good contact, hence the continuity test.

Comment: Thanks - I edited the original with a bit more information. But yes, I do mean a cheap plastic one